# Redirecting MySQL errors and slow logs into another database

Tags: mysql, logs, performance, error-log, slow-log

I am running a number of MySQL servers as slaves and masters. It is quite annoying to look for slow logs and errors in every server, so I would like to log all the errors into an external database.

```
    DB1    DB2    DBn ...
      \      |      /
       \     |     /          <-- error logs and slow logs
        \    |    /
[MySQL error & slow log database]
```

Is there some simple way of doing it?
Or I do need to write some scripts and stuff?

P.S. I hope you appreciate my superb ASCII diagraming skills

Comment: I added additional info to my answer concerning error logs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you ever considered converting the slow log into a MyISAM table?

As for MySQL 5.1.30, you can choose the format of the slow log and general log as either TABLE or FILE by means of the [log_output](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-output) option. [It is also available in MySQL 5.5](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-output).

To support the TABLE option for log_output, MySQL provided two tables:

- `mysql.slow_log`
- `mysql.general_log`

For the sake of this question, I will discuss only `mysql.slow_log`

By default, this is `mysql.slow_log`:

```
mysql> show create table mysql.slow_log\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: slow_log
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `slow_log` (
  `start_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `user_host` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `query_time` time NOT NULL,
  `lock_time` time NOT NULL,
  `rows_sent` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rows_examined` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `db` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `last_insert_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `insert_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `server_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sql_text` mediumtext NOT NULL
) ENGINE=CSV DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Slow log'
1 row in set (0.10 sec)

mysql>
```

The slow_log table uses the CSV storage engine. Please note that a CSV table cannot be indexed. That's not very useful for doing analysis by date and time. GOOD NEWS: You can convert it to a MyISAM table.

In order to facilitate a MyISAM-based slow log, perform the following:

Step01) Make mysql.slow_log a MyISAM table

```
ALTER TABLE mysql.slow_log ENGINE-MyISAM;
```

Step02) Index to timestamp column called `start_time`

```
ALTER TABLE mysql.slow_log ADD INDEX (start_time);
```

Step03) Add the following lines to the my.cnf (or my.ini)

```
[mysqld]
slow-query-log
log-output=TABLE
```

Step04) Restart MySQL

For Linux

```
service mysql restart
```

or for Windows

```
net stop mysql
net start mysql
```

Step05) Run the following command in MySQL

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'long_query_time';
```

By default [long_query_time](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_long_query_time) is 10 seconds

Step06) Run this command

```
mysql> SELECT SLEEP(15);
```

If long_query_time is 10 seconds, this SELECT should deliberately be placed in mysql.slow_log.

Step07) Run this command

```
mysql> SELECT sql_text FROM mysql.slow_log;
```

If you see any row in the table with the `SELECT SLEEP(15);`, CONGRATULATIONS !!!

You can now run SELECT queries against `mysql.slow_log` to copy some or all of the rows to other tables or other databases.

I have posted past answers in conjunction with this subject:

- `Mar 30, 2012` : [MySQL slow log configuration](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15863/mysql-slow-log-configuration/15890#15890)
- `Nov 18, 2011` : [Create a custom log table in MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8105/create-a-custom-log-table-in-mysql/8117#8117)
- `Jun 30, 2011` : [How do I output MySQL logs to syslog?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3552/how-do-i-output-mysql-logs-to-syslog/3571#3571)

## UPDATE 2012-11-12 17:00 EDT

In all fairness, the question did ask about error logs. I did not explicitly include anything about it. I will include some code that addresses how to

Let's say the error log is defined on any DB server as follows:

```
[mysqld]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
```

You could create a script like this:

```
ERROR_LOG=/var/log/mysqld.log
LOG_LINES=/tmp/general-log-lines.txt
ERROR_FOLDER=<folder where to copy logs>
ERROR_TARGET=${ERROR_FOLDER}/`hostname`-DB-Errors.txt
NEWCOUNT=`wc -l < ${ERROR_LOG}`
if [ -f ${LOG_LINES} ]
then
    OLDCOUNT=`cat ${LOG_LINES} | awk '{print $1}'`
    if [ ${OLDCOUNT} -lt ${NEWCOUNT} ]
    then
        (( DIFF = NEWCOUNT - OLDCOUNT ))
        tail -${DIFF} < ${ERROR_LOG} >> ${ERROR_TARGET}
        echo ${NEWCOUNT} > ${LOG_LINES}
    fi
fi
```

or if you want to collect and reset the error log without a mysql restart (linux only) you can use this (This technique could never be done in Windows because the Windows OS locks the error log file from external writing):

```
ERROR_LOG=/var/log/mysqld.log
LOG_LINES=/tmp/general-log-lines.txt
ERROR_FOLDER=<folder where to copy logs>
ERROR_TARGET=${ERROR_FOLDER}/`hostname`-DB-Errors.txt
NEWCOUNT=`wc -l < ${ERROR_LOG}`
if [ -f ${LOG_LINES} ]
then
    OLDCOUNT=`cat ${LOG_LINES} | awk '{print $1}'`
    if [ ${OLDCOUNT} -lt ${NEWCOUNT} ]
    then
        (( DIFF = NEWCOUNT - OLDCOUNT ))
        tail -${DIFF} < ${ERROR_LOG} >> ${ERROR_TARGET}
        echo -n > ${ERROR_LOG}
        echo 0 > ${LOG_LINES}
    fi
fi
```

Place this script on every DB server. Setup a crontab for this script to go off every 5 minutes. Make sure `ERROR_FOLDER` is set to a common shared folder.

## UPDATE 2012-11-12 17:24 EDT

For clarification, running MySQL `FLUSH LOGS;` is insufficient because...

- For all text-based logs, [`FLUSH LOGS;`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/flush.html) closes and reopens. No rotation is provided by mysqld
- For binary logs, `FLUSH LOGS;` will...

  - Close current binary log
  - Rotate to a new binary log
  - Open new binary log
- For MySQL 5.5, [`FLUSH ERROR LOGS;`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/flush.html) closes and reopens the error log. No rotation is provided

This is why some scripting is necessary

Comment: hmz ... and then I can use replication to replicate logs to a central log database. Sounds good. Cheers.

Comment: And the error log ?

Comment: @AlainCollins The last link in my answer (Jun 30, 2011) gives the principle code on how to get chunks of text logs and copy it elsewhere. Tell you what: I put such code in my answer.

Comment: @AlainCollins Mission accomplished. I added the code I promised.

Comment: @AlainCollins thanks for the vote of confidence.

Answer (score -1):

The slow logs are just text files, so there's no MySQL way of dealing with them.

The general process is to move/rename the files and then do a MySQL FLUSH, which will tell MySQL to start a new log file.

Then take the moved/renamed file and ship it off to your log server.  Seems like a simple bash script would work.

Hope that helps.