# How often does the slow_log table get updated in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, performance, slow-log

I've changed the `long_query_time` from 10 secs to 5 secs. I haven't seen any queries logged for a few hours now. Am I supposed to tweak my database for the slow_log table to gets updated more often?

There were slow queries that took longer than 10 seconds and I've already dealt with them. However, the first byte time for my WordPress website is still > 3 seconds according to `tools.pingdom.com`.

**Updates:**

I've just changed the `long_query_time` to 1 sec and still, I haven't seen any slow queries logged yet. Could it be possible that I now have no queries that takes longer than 1 sec to execute (that seems too good to be true, doesn't it?)?

I've seen queries that took longer than 1 sec now so everything is working fine for me - I see the slow queries that I need to see.

*How I got the slow queries to be logged in the slow_log table in mysql database?* 
I'm using Amazon RDS MySQL, so as soon as I changed `slow_query_log` to 1, the slow queries appear in the slow_log table.

Comment: I suggest you set the `long_query_time` to `0.0` seconds (yes, **zero**) for a few minutes (or more but note that teh log will grow rather fast, probably to GBs size). Then you can analyze what will be essentially all queries/statements that hit the database in that period. There are some good tools for this (search for maatkit). You may find that info far more useful. It's not uncommon for a plugin to be sending hundreds of requests per second to the database. A 10ms query that is sent 100 times per second is affecting performance more than a 2 seconds query that runs once a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slow query log gets updated once a query is completed and the query time is  beyond or equal to value set in `long_query_time`.

So it could mean either good or bad. The good is all the queries completed within `long_query_time`. The bad is the slow query is still running.

To experience a slow query you can try subqueries with multiple level.

Comment: there's another way to get queries logged than just long-running. You can set `--log-queries-not-using-indexes`

Comment: Yes, you are right!

Answer (score 3):

By default, slow queries are not recorded anywhere.

There are three(3) ways to activate the Slow Query Log

### ACTIVATION #1 : Text File

To log slow queries to a text file, please add the following to the `/etc/my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
long-query-time=5
log-output=FILE
slow-query-log
slow-query-log-file=/var/log/mysql-slow-queries.log
```

### ACTIVATION #2 : CSV Table (`mysql.slow_log`)

To log slow queries to `mysql.slow_log`, please add the following to the `/etc/my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
long-query-time=5
log-output=TABLE
slow-query-log
```

### ACTIVATION #3 : Both Methods (Text File and Table)

```
[mysqld]
long-query-time=5
log-output=FILE,TABLE
slow-query-log
slow-query-log-file=/var/log/mysql-slow-queries.log
```

### SUMMARY

Once you edit /etc/my.cnf (or my.ini for Windows), you must restart mysql

- For Linux, `service mysql restart`
- For Windows
- `net stop mysql`
- `net start mysql`

If you would like to test the slow log after the mysql restart, simply run this:

```
SELECT SLEEP(12);
```

If [long-query-time](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_long_query_time) >= 12, this statement should land the the slow log.

Here are the variables used in the above methods

- [long-query-time](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_long_query_time) (Set this to 0 so everything and its grandmother lands in the Slow Query Log)
- [log-output](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-output)
- [slow-query-log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_slow_query_log)
- [slow-query-log-file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_slow_query_log_file)

For more information on Slow Query Logging, please read the MySQL Documentation

- [**The Slow Query Log**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/slow-query-log.html)
- [**Selecting General Query and Slow Query Log Output Destinations**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/log-destinations.html)

### CAVEAT

If you decide to use `mysql.slow_log`, keep in mind that the default `mysql.slow_log` is a CSV table. You can query against `mysql.slow_log`, but the table has no index.

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 1
Server version: 5.5.29 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2012, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show create table mysql.slow_log\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: slow_log
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `slow_log` (
  `start_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `user_host` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `query_time` time NOT NULL,
  `lock_time` time NOT NULL,
  `rows_sent` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rows_examined` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `db` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `last_insert_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `insert_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `server_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sql_text` mediumtext NOT NULL
) ENGINE=CSV DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Slow log'
1 row in set (0.05 sec)

mysql>
```

If you would like the slow log to be a MyISAM so you can query it like any other table, please run the following:

```
ALTER TABLE mysql.slow_log ENGINE = MyISAM;
ALTER TABLE mysql.slow_log ADD INDEX (start_time);
```

Here is what you should see afterwards:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE mysql.slow_log ENGINE = MyISAM;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> ALTER TABLE mysql.slow_log ADD INDEX (start_time);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> show create table mysql.slow_log\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: slow_log
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `slow_log` (
  `start_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `user_host` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `query_time` time NOT NULL,
  `lock_time` time NOT NULL,
  `rows_sent` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rows_examined` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `db` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `last_insert_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `insert_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `server_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sql_text` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  KEY `start_time` (`start_time`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Slow log'
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

You can read my past answers on this:

- `Nov 18, 2011` : [Create a custom log table in MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8105/create-a-custom-log-table-in-mysql/8117#8117)
- `Mar 30, 2012` : [MySQL slow log configuration](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15863/mysql-slow-log-configuration/15890#15890)

Comment: The question was "How often does slow_log table gets updated in MySQL?"...

Comment: @mfouilleul Sorry for the overkill. Since fuzzybee did not get anything recorded, I gave an expanded overview of setting up Slow Query Logging to give fuzzybee something to compare.

Comment: Thanks @RolandoMySQLDBA, sorry I may have not made it clear that I did get slow queries logged, just too impatient to see the next slow queries after some tuning :)