# Is there a way to run mysqldumpslow against slow queries logged to a table?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5, amazon-rds, performance, slow-log

AWS RDS by default logs slow queries to a database table.

Is there a way to run mysqldumpslow against that table, without exporting it to a file first?  Or is there a better way to get a report of slow queries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[mysqldumpslow](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldumpslow.html) only works on text files, so you need to forget about using it.

The table `mysql.slow_log` is a  CSV table by default.

```
mysql> show create table mysql.slow_log\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: slow_log
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `slow_log` (
  `start_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `user_host` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `query_time` time NOT NULL,
  `lock_time` time NOT NULL,
  `rows_sent` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rows_examined` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `db` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `last_insert_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `insert_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `server_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sql_text` mediumtext NOT NULL
) ENGINE=CSV DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Slow log'
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

You do not want to query against a CSV table as it will do full table scans every time.

What you can do is create a copy of the table into another database and index `start_time`

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS my_slow_log;
CREATE DATABASE my_slow_log;
CREATE TABLE my_slow_log.slow_log LIKE mysql.slow_log;
ALTER TABLE my_slow_log.slow_log ADD INDEX (start_time);
ALTER TABLE my_slow_log.slow_log DISABLE KEYS;
INSERT INTO my_slow_log.slow_log
    SELECT * FROM mysql.slow_log
;
ALTER TABLE my_slow_log.slow_log ENABLE KEYS;
```

Then, you can query against `my_slow_log.slow_log` by datetime values

I have discussed this before

- `Nov 18, 2011` : [Create a custom log table in MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8105/create-a-custom-log-table-in-mysql/8117#8117)
- `Mar 30, 2012` : [MySQL slow log configuration](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15863/mysql-slow-log-configuration/15890#15890)

**Give it a Try !!!**

CAVEAT: You would have to reload the data every time you want the latest slow logs.

In that event, if you want just want slow logs from midnight 3 days ago, do this:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE my_slow_log.slow_log;
ALTER TABLE my_slow_log.slow_log DISABLE KEYS;
INSERT INTO my_slow_log.slow_log
    SELECT * FROM mysql.slow_log
    WHERE start_time >= DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY) + INTERVAL 0 SECOND;
;
ALTER TABLE my_slow_log.slow_log ENABLE KEYS;
```

or just in the last 3 hours

```
TRUNCATE TABLE my_slow_log.slow_log;
ALTER TABLE mysql.slow_log DISABLE KEYS;
INSERT INTO my_slow_log.slow_log
    SELECT * FROM mysql.slow_log
    WHERE start_time >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 3 HOUR);
;
ALTER TABLE my_slow_log.slow_log; ENABLE KEYS;
```

## UPDATE 2014-12-11 14:50 EST

Your comment

> This makes querying the data a bit quicker, but I'm interested in how to provide a summary of slow queries that I can then pass along to our developers

You could present this to your developers by requesting slow logs entries as follows:

Today's 20 worst performing queries

```
SELECT query_time,sql_text
FROM my_slow_log.slow_log
WHERE start_time >= DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 0 SECOND
ORDER BY query_time DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

Count of Slow Queries By the Hour over the Last 2 Weeks

```
SELECT hr,COUNT(1) SlowQueries FROM
(
    SELECT (unix_timestamp(start_time) - MOD(unix_timestamp(start_time),3600)) hr
    FROM my_slow_log.slow_log
    WHERE start_time >= DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK) + INTERVAL 0 SECOND
) A GROUP BY hr;
```

Count of Slow Queries By the Minute over the Last 6 Hours

```
SELECT mn,COUNT(1) SlowQueries FROM
(
    SELECT (unix_timestamp(start_time) - MOD(unix_timestamp(starttime),60)) mn
    FROM my_slow_log.slow_log
    WHERE start_time >= ( NOW() - INTERVAL 6 HOUR )
) A GROUP BY mn;
```

Queries like these can give you stats when slow queries run and what the actual queries were.

You can send these queries to a text file and send them to the developers

```
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=rootpassword
MYSQL_CONN="-u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"
SQL="SELECT query_time,sql_text FROM my_slow_log.slow_log"
SQL="${SQL} WHERE start_time >= DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 0 SECOND"
SQL="${SQL} ORDER BY query_time DESC LIMIT 20"
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -ANe"${SQL}" > Slow_Queries_Report.txt
```

Comment: This makes querying the data a bit quicker, but I'm interested in how to provide a summary of slow queries that I can then pass along to our developers.

Comment: In top 20 query, this seems odd to me: WHERE start_time >= DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 0 SECOND. start time now? should it not be some time back?

Comment: @LennartRolland DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 0 SECOND brings back midnight of today